# Defer parsing JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I read that deferring the JavaScript files leads to smooth opening of the page and less load time..... using the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
alert(document.getElementById("p1").firstChild.nodeValue);
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
alert(document.getElementById("p1").firstChild.nodeValue);
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
alert(document.getElementById("p1").firstChild.nodeValue);
</script>
```

I am referring to the "defer" in the above code but I read that it only works in IE. Is there any other method for deferring the parsing of JS? I already have compressed it.

Comment: You could move the less important scripts to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove 2 of the script-elements and add an onload in the first. In this onload-function you can write the script-elements to the dom and they will be loaded async. Check out this link: [Dynamic javascript loading](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html)

Answer (score 0):

I should attach a event on the `window.onload` that fires when the window has been loaded.

example:

```
function deferMethod() {
  // you're code here
}

// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", deferMethod, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", deferMethod);
else 
  window.onload = deferMethod;
```